# declaration of callback function and return type

Tags: pointers, callback

in the following function, for callback function `start_routine`, the return type is `void **`

```
 int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
               void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

but when we define the callback function, it is like this:

```
void func(void *)
```

I know it is a function, but I thought at least the callback function should be like:

```
void* func(void *);
```

where I'm wrong? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`void func(void *)` is just a normal function which returns nothing and takes a `void*`. It **cannot** be placed as a function's argument.

`void* func(void *)` is similar to above, the only difference being that it returns a `void*` pointer.

A callback function looks like this `return_type (*function_name)(arguments)`. Here, an example is `void* (*start_routine)(void *)`. This is a **valid** function argument.

The `pthread_create` function takes as its second last argument a pointer to a function `start_routine` whose return type is `void*` and has only one argument of type `void*`.

An excerpt from this page: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html

*Sometimes people get confused when more stars are thrown in:*

```
void *(*foo)(int *);
```

*Here, the key is to read inside-out; notice that the innermost element of the expression is `*foo`, and that otherwise it looks like a normal function declaration. `*foo` should refer to a function that returns a `void*` and takes an `int*`. Consequently, foo is a pointer to just such a function.*

Comment: so the callback function should be defined like `void* func(void *)`, but why in examples, they define it as `void func(void *)`?

Comment: No, the callback function is defined as `void* func(void*)` only. `void func(void*)` will give a syntax error. See `thread_start` on this: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html

Comment: ah, they call it like: `pthread_create(&tinfo[tnum].thread_id, &attr, &thread_start, &tinfo[tnum])` , there is a `&` before thread_start, I'm wondering whether this `&` can be avoided or not?

Comment: No, appending `&` gives the address of that function, which is assigned to the function pointer argument. Is it clear now?

Comment: I think function name is the same as its address, so thread_start is equal to &thread_start, isn't it?

Comment: Oh yes, I had forgotten. `thread_start` is equal to `&thread_start` !